# Magento And- OR query

Tags: magento

We are having two attributes check_in_stock and show_in_front. I would like to have magento equivalent query for :
`where (check_in_stock > 0 OR (check_in_stock=0 and show_in_front=1))`.

Please help me to find the equivalent magento query

Comment: Take a look magento  http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/using_collections_in_magento ,  search for '// Add OR condition:'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use the SQL queries like:

```
Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()->getSelect()->where('check_in_stock > 0 OR (check_in_stock=0 and show_in_front=1)')
```

This wil lcreate an sql output like:

```
"SELECT `e`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` WHERE (check_in_stock > 0 OR (check_in_stock=0 and show_in_front=1))"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I would like to use magento addAttributeToFilter.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Itera Research,

Here I am happy to share reply from our Magento team lead, please check below:

"First you need to lookup visibility and status attributes ids

select `attribute_id` from `eav_attribute` where `attribute_code` = 'visibility';

in my case it returns 102

select `attribute_id` from `eav_attribute` where `attribute_code` = 'status';

in my case it returns 96

and substitute these ids to the following query

SELECT `e`.*, `at_qty`.`qty`, `at_status`.`value` AS `status`, `at_visibility`.`value` AS `visibility` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_item` AS `at_qty` ON (at_qty.`product_id`=e.entity_id) AND (at_qty.stock_id=1)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_status` ON (`at_status`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_status`.`attribute_id` = '96') AND (`at_status`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_visibility` ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_visibility`.`attribute_id` = '102') AND (`at_visibility`.`store_id` = 0)
 inner join `cataloginventory_stock_status` as `ss` on (`ss`.`product_id` = `e`.`entity_id`)
 where `at_visibility`.`value` = 1 and `ss`.`stock_status` = 1

Hope this helps,

if not, please ping me a message,

Jen Zorina

Itera Research